# SOLR search and NGrams

Tags: solr, n-gram

I am trying to implement address search and have tried using NGrams.

The schema definition is as follows:

```
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
     <analyzer type="index">
       <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="6"/>
    </analyzer>
     <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
     </analyzer>
   </fieldType>
```

From what I have understood is that we should not be implementing NGramFilterFactory at the query level.

The issue I am facing is:

I am trying to search for the misspelled address: 1 ODETE COURT RINGWOOD (query)
The address to which I am trying to match is: 1 ODETTE COURT RINGWOOD (index)

and I am getting all the addresses with the word COURT in them. Is there a way to tweak SOLR to return the indexed address?

Thanks.

Comment: Ngrams aren't really useful to match misspellings; have you looked at the suggester support or spell checker instead? In this case you'd probably be better off if you're trying to autocomplete the text and used an edge ngram tokenizer (so that the user saw `1 ODETTE COURT` when they had typed `1 ODET`)

Comment: I haven't looked at those. I do have other logic built in using fuzzy matches etc to get to the right address, but I was hoping if I can get to this type of address mismatch so I won't need to fall back to the fuzzy matching logic. I will try out the edge ngram tokenizer as well, but was hoping  that ngram would be of help. Would having ngram filter at the query level be of any help?

Comment: It would give you a lot of false positives, so not really. An ngram filter does not help with misspellings; it helps with exact partial matches (i.e. where the token matches, but only a part of the token matches what has been entered). If you use an ngram filter on query, you end up with any document that has a letter / sequence from your query somewhere in the field being brought up as a match.

Comment: Thanks. Been trying out the suggester and it looks promising. Just need to figure out how to get 1 1 ODETTE COURT RINGWOOD and 1 ODETTE COURT RINGWOOD as search results if I search for 1 ODETE COURT RINGWOOD. Currently, it is giving me 1 ODETTE COURT RINGWOOD for searching 1 ODETE COURT RINGWOOD and 1 1 ODETTE COURT RINGWOOD for searching 1 1 ODETE COURT RINGWOOD.

Comment: That would depend on which suggester you're using. The FuzzyLookupFactory for example has a `maxEdits` parameter that you can set to `2` to allow more edits. You can also use a specific lookup/index chain for processing a query to the suggesters, for example to remove duplicate letters.